# PowerBI: how to get average of sum of multiple categories

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, categories

For a report, I would like to have the average of a sum over 2 categories (date_type_project & ID).
In PowerBI, I would like to have 2 cards with 1 number. There'll be cards with the numbers:

- data_type_project - non-standard, 30.44
- data_type_project - standard, 9.47

The numbers are composed as follow: (29 + 33 + 20.25 + 39.5) / 4 = 30.44
and (3.5 + 25.5 + 9.75 + 17.5 + 17.25 + 14.5 + 1.5 + 1.25 + 4.5) / 9 = 9.47

How can I calculate this number in DAX?

[image: Pivot table example]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following and use [ISINSCOPE()](https://dax.guide/isinscope/) function:

```
measure_hours = 
    -- will check, if 'Table'[ID] is in current filter context
    var cond = ISINSCOPE('Table'[ID])
RETURN
    IF(
        cond,
        SUM('Table'[hours]),
        AVERAGE('Table'[hours])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure and place it in place of hours

```
Measure = SUM([Hours])/COUNT([ID])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that is answering my question: I've created a measure. Then, put it in a card visual and set the legend to 'data_type_project'. Thank you for the help! :)

```
measure = 
AVERAGEX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Table'[ID])),
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[hours]))
)
```